# How to get path from a QStandardItemModel using a QModelIndex?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to get the path of a directory from QStandardItemModel using a QModelIndex. Is it possible? I saw that I can use `QString QFileSystemModel::filePath ( const QModelIndex & index ) const`. But it crashes when I run this code:

```
QString _path = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(model)->filePath(modelIndex);
```

Also it crashes if I create an instance of a `QFileSystemModel` and pass a `QModelIndex`:

```
QFileSystemModel* fileSystem = new QFileSystemModel();
QString myPath = fileSystem->filePath(modelIndex);
```

Comment: I don't understand, what has QStandardItemModel to do with the issue?

Comment: If you try to cast a `QStandardItemModel` to a `QFileSystemModel` this should not work.

Comment: @peppe my `model` has type of `QStandardItemModel`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation

> `QFileSystemModel` will not fetch any files or directories until `setRootPath()` is called.

I strongly recommend doing so.

If more questions arise make sure to check out [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qfilesystemmodel.html#details).

Comment: Thank you! Your advice is pretty clear. But i did it it in another way. I added a column to the `model` that stores a file path.